# Retrieve a Button By String Type Name of its ID

Tags: android

As in android we access every widget by its id just like
 `findViewById(R.id.Button1);`

But if I want to access this ID by its name( that is of String type) how is it possible?

I have 18 buttons in my XML files by name imageButton_0, imageButton_1 ... imageButton_17.  I want to access a random button, so I created a random number between 0 ... 17. Let's random number created is 
`rand = 1;`

```
public void putImagesOnBoard(){
       for(int i =0 ;i<imagesArray.length; i++){
           for(int j =0; j<2; j++){
               int randomPosition = new Random().nextInt(positionArray.length - count);
               String str = "imageButton" + Integer.toString(positionArray[randomPosition]);
               ImageButton btn = How access by name of button that is int String str (For example imageButton_1)
               int id = R.id.imageButton_1;


               swap(positionArray, randomPosition, positionArray.length - count);
               count = count+1;
           }
       }
```

Thanks for Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

well, you can try this 
try to add these id's in a resource file names "my_resource"

`int imageID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource", "id", getPackageName());`

This will get your actual Integer ID
Your final code would be

```
public void putImagesOnBoard(){
       for(int i =0 ;i<imagesArray.length; i++){
           for(int j =0; j<2; j++){
               int randomPosition = new Random().nextInt(positionArray.length - count);
               String str = "imageButton" + Integer.toString(positionArray[randomPosition]);
               int imageID = getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource", str, getPackageName());
               int id = imageID;


               swap(positionArray, randomPosition, positionArray.length - count);
               count = count+1;
           }
       }
```

Comment: this id that we will create inside my_resource folder will not be of that imageButton's id but it would be a new id.

Comment: And how we can set image to integer type id as it is not of any Button type?

Comment: Note: An ID is a simple resource that is referenced using the value provided in the name attribute (not the name of the XML file). As such, you can combine ID resources with other simple resources in the one XML file, under one <resources> element. Also, remember that an ID resources does not reference an actual resource item; it is simply a unique ID that you can attach to other resources or use as a unique integer in your application.

Comment: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources)

Comment: I correctify it by using TAG  by adding xml code `android:tag="imageButton_0"` and in java file I use `String str = "imageButton" + Integer.toString(positionArray[randomPosition]);
                ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_game_board);
                ImageButton btn = constraintLayout.findViewWithTag(str);
                btn.setImageResource(R.mipmap.sandle_0);`